# Issue understanding CouchBase connection with PHP

Tags: php, couchbase

I just installed CouchBase and the .dll files for XAMPP. I am following their example on how to connect: "Hello Couchbase" https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/php/start-using-sdk.html

This code:

```
$bucketName = "default";

// Connect to Couchbase Server
$cluster = new CouchbaseCluster("couchbase://127.0.0.1");
$bucket = $cluster->openBucket($bucketName);
```

gives me:
LCB_AUTH_ERROR: Authentication failed. You may have provided an invalid username/password combination

I have a fresh installation, and following their guide #1, what am I doing wrong? I don't remember setting a password, I went to the CouchBase admin page and I can't find a way to change any password.

Comment: What version of Couchbase and PHP are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

I sympathize here -- I'm having the same error (and no, it's not you, the docs have been neglected).  Instantiating the `CouchbaseCluster` doesn't throw the error, it's actually the `openBucket()` method that causes problems, and for me, the problem was that the bucket didn't exist (it would be nice if the Couchbase error were in the right ballpark instead of bumbling around in irrelevant confusion).  Here's some code that worked for me:

```
$cluster = new CouchbaseCluster('http://127.0.0.1:8091');
$manager = $cluster->manager('MYUSER', 'MYPASSWORD');
$manager->createBucket('new_bucket');
```

This does throw some errors:

```
[cb,WARN] (htconfig L:130 I:0) <couchbase:8091> (CTX=0x5601e6fd7e90,bc_http) Got 404 on config stream. Assuming terse URI not supported on cluster
[cb,EROR] (htconfig L:122 I:0) <couchbase:8091> (CTX=0x5601e6fd7e90,bc_http) Got 404 on config stream. Assuming bucket does not exist as we've tried both URL types
[cb,EROR] (htconfig L:142 I:0) <couchbase:8091> (CTX=0x5601e6fd7e90,bc_http) Got non-success HTTP status code 404
```

But it does work.  The Couchbase forums are a better place for these types of questions -- they respond pretty quickly over there.